# Shouldn't bounty sponsor get some reputation for upvoting the sponsored question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, bounties

Here's something that just popped in my head - when someone sponsors a bounty on somebody else's question, this question gets extra attention and the original asker might get some extra reputation for that. Shouldn't the sponsor get some reputation as well, or - say - 4 points for the asker, one for the sponsor for each upvote etc?

Comment: I wouldn't take a point away from the OP's rep gain to give to the sponsor, since there's no way to be sure that the bounty has anything to do with a given upvote (even if it is likely). I like the idea as a way to encourage bounties and allow sponsors to recoup their reputation expenditure though (to answer the following comment...)

Comment: Adding extra complexity to solve... what problem?

Comment: As @NickStauner said, to encourage bounties.

Comment: Is there evidence that not enough bounties are set now, and more are needed? As of now: 425 bounties on [so]; 41 bounties on [math.se], etc.

Comment: ...only 3 on security.stackexchange.com. Interesting point though.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills: several sites have zero or few bounties, especially including beta sites. Maybe this idea would be especially helpful for them. I just went through about 20 and only found about 5 with more than 3 active bounties.  Most had zero.

Comment: I'd prefer 5 points for the questioner, 1 point for the promoter.  Or -2 to the questioner, -1 to the promoter.

Comment: @NickStauner That still does not demonstrate the existence of a problem to be solved. Is it true that users of those sites want to set bounties, but are deterred by high cost? Are such concerns voiced on their metas? Perhaps they don't set bounties because they don't need them: on a low-traffic site, a new question can stay on the front page for a few days.

Comment: I don't have evidence that bounties increase traffic (i.e., generate it, not just redirect it), but I'd bet on it. Low traffic affects overall rep income too, so the cost would be worse on low traffic sites. Rep production is important for a beta site because several users need access to privileges if the site graduates. That's part of why I'm not offering any bounties on CogSci personally. Bounties aren't for brand new questions anyway. The first question eligible for bounty on Travel is two pages back (showing the default 15 Qs per page), and they only have one featured question ATM.

Answer (score 2):

The sponsor is already paying some of his reputation to promote the question, if he could get it back just from the act of offering the bounty, why bother making him pay these points to begin with?

The whole point of StackExchange is that you get reputation by good questions/answers, not by good deeds, noble as they may be. If you offer a bounty it means you're willing to make some sacrifice - taking away the price doesn't make much sense, it reduces the worth of that deed.

Worse, it could lead to abuse. People might offer bounties left and right just for the chance to get some reputation out of it. It would also lower the chances of a bounty getting attention.

Comment: This doesn't propose to take away the price; it pays it back if the question *deserves* attention. The community's actions won't reward abuse, and offering bounties "left and right" wouldn't net a sponsor reputation if the proposed reward isn't too obscenely high. E.g., how often is a sponsor going to profit if the bonus is +2 rep per upvote on the sponsored question? It only promotes abuse if you're implementing the idea poorly.

Comment: @NickStauner, who's to say which question deserves more attention than others? By subjectively deciding that, you hurt the other questions. That's legitimate only if it's made to cost you something. Anyway, I don't mind a "finder-reward" that caps at +2/+4, but getting significant reward over someone elses' work is fundamentally wrong. Otherwise, I could just offer a bounty over one of Jon Skeets' early answers and go live like a king in Patagonia.

Comment: The sponsor can pay to say, and the community can decide whether s/he's right. Again, "significant reward" sounds like poor implementation.

Comment: Well, the suggestion was something per vote, that's unbounded and bad. If it's bounded, like I said, it could be valid, although a little pointless IMHO (you just lost 50 rep, here's +2 back because someone else also thinks it's a good question). Remember - my original assumption is that you don't need to reward good deeds by rep.

Comment: Again, bounding it at a low number is just poor implementation. This is starting to smell like a straw man attack. Why not bound it at the price of the bounty so that gain is impossible?  Or half the price so that cost is halved if the community really loves the question?

Comment: You don't think the reward should be significant, and you don't think it should be bounded by a small value. I'm confused now. If you have some implementation in mind, please share, and we can let the community decide.

Comment: +2 to the sponsor per upvote on the OP, bounded at half the price of the bounty is one combination of the examples I've already mentioned above. Additional considerations might include the reason for offering the bounty – sharing rep changes on a specific, existing answer's votes would seem a little more appropriate if the bounty is intended to reward that answer. Also, whether to share downvote losses is optional.

Comment: At 1 point per upvote for the promoter, it would take 50 upvotes to fully recoup the bounty.  That seems pretty unlikely.  Especially since you can't set a bounty immediately on a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the point of posting a bounty on a question.  The goal is to get an answer.

If the person who posted the bounty (*OP or random user*) is really interested in  reputation they can research and post an answer, if they are motivated enough to offer some of their reputation for an question they did not write, they are interested in getting an answer.

Comment: What makes you think he's "missed the point"? Your answer seems to miss that of the OP...Also, bounties have more uses than encouraging answers.